# Count End of Line in C++ whilst reading the 'words'

Tags: c++, ifstream, word-count, line-count

I'm writing a program which as its first step reads from some ~30MB text files.
These files are a series of numbers between 0 and 255, with occasional line breaks (ImageJ text images, via RGB stacks).
I can read the data into a `vector<int>` without any problems, and form a `vector<vector<int> >` for the RGB part also. However, I'd like to know the height and width of my images.

The total is available via `myVector[0,1,2].size()`, but unless I also know the aspect ratio I can't get height/width from this.

If I use `file.get(nextChar); if (nextChar == '\n'){...}` then the code will continue to read across, afaik.

I tried reading the characters on a line separately from reading in the files, but in addition to the increased runtime (which isn't such a big deal), I have a more serious problem in that the files contain `tab` spaces, not real spaces, so whilst I originally thought each number was 4 characters, eg `123(space)` or `12(space)(space)` etc, it turns out they'd be `123(tab)` and `12(tab)`, which have different character counts.

How can I count my words per line? Example code is below:

```
void imageStack::readFile(const char *file, std::vector<int> &values)
{
    std::ifstream filestream;
    filestream.open(file);

    if (!filestream.fail())
    {
        std::cout<< "File opened successfully: " << file << std::endl;
        int countW=0;
        char next;
        while (!filestream.eof())
        {
            int currentValue;
            filestream >> currentValue;
            values.push_back(currentValue);
            countW++;
            if (filestream.get(next)=='\n')
                // This doesn't work, but I think if I used filestream.get(next);
                // if (next == '\n') that would check correctly,
                // it would just move the file marker
            {
                std::cout<< "countW = " << countW << std::endl;
            }
        }
        filestream.close();
        values.pop_back();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File did not open! Filename was " << file << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Code below doesn't count accurately:

```
std::vector<int> imageStack::getDimensions(const std::string fileName)
{
    std::vector<int> dim(2);

    std::stringstream rfN;
    rfN << fileName << "R";
    std::string rFileName = rfN.str();
    const char *file_ptr;

    file_ptr = rFileName.c_str();
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(file_ptr);

    int widthCount=-1, heightCount=-1;  
    if (!file.fail())
    {
        char next;
        int counterW = 0;
        int counterH = 0;
        while(file.get(next))
        {
            counterW++;
            if (next == '\n')
            {
                counterH++;
                if (widthCount == -1)
                {
                    std::cout << "The first line has " << counterW << " characters." << std::endl;
                }
                if (widthCount != -1 && widthCount != counterW)
                {
                    //~ std::cout<< "The width counter didn't get the same number every time!" << std::endl;
                    //~ std::cout<< "widthCount = " << widthCount << std::endl;
                    //~ std::cout<< "counterW = " << counterW << std::endl;
                }
                widthCount = counterW;
                counterW = 0;
            }
            heightCount = counterH;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    //~ std::cout   << "Values found for width and height are " 
                //~ << widthCount << ", " << heightCount << std::endl;

    dim[0] = ((widthCount-1)/4);
    dim[1] = heightCount;
    return dim;
}
```

Comment: You might find it useful to use nested loops to read a line at a time, then process the characters in that line (i.e. `std::string line; while (std::getline(file, line)) { ++line_num; std::istringstream iss(line); int value; while (iss >> value) ... }`.

Comment: (Separately, your `!filestream.eof()` is broken - search stackoverflow for "C++ while eof" and you'll get dozens of explanations)

Comment: @TonyD Thanks - the line by line this is probably much more sensible, and I'll take a look at the fixes for the !..eof() part - I knew it duplicated the last result but was currently just removing it - quick fix but bad coding.